# Laplace Transform and Fourier Transform With Neumann Boundary Conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, laplace-transform, boundary-value-problem

Suppose I'm doing a Laplace Transform or Fourier Transform with respect to $t$ to solve a PDE, and I have Neumann (partial derivative) boundary conditions, such as $$u_t(a, t) = f(t)$$

Can I just translate these directly, such as $$U_t(a, s) = F(s)$$

or do I have to apply the same transform of derivative formulas used to transform partial derivatives in the PDE to the left hand side of the boundary condition equations, i.e.$$sU(a, s) - u(a, 0) = F(s)$$

or is some other transformation correct?

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what the problem you actually want to solve is? Do you have a PDE or an ODE for time only? If you have a PDE with derivatives in say $x$ and $t$, then generally you would use the Fourier Transform in the spatial direction $x$ -- ie $u_x \rightarrow ik\hat{u}$ while taking the Fourier Transform of a derivative in time would then simply lead to $\hat{u_t}$. You can derive those straight from the definitions of the Fourier Transform and/or can probably find them pretty easily online elsewhere.

Comment: As for the Neumann BC, if you're transforming the equation from physical space to Fourier space, then you would also do the same thing for the BCs as well. Don't think anything would be different in that case.

Comment: @Mjoseph The problem would be some suitable PDE in multiple variables, i.e., $u_t(x, t) = u_{xx}(x, t)$, where one of the boundary conditions is, i.e., $u_t(1, t) = t$.

Comment: The Fourier Transform of the equation would then be $\hat{u}_t=-k^2\hat{u}$ and you're boundary condition would be $\hat{u}_t=\hat{t}$. To actually find $\hat{t}$ you would just make use of the definition. In this case, we're transforming the variable $x$, so the function $t$ would be treated as a constant in the integral since it would be with respect to $x$.

Comment: @Mjoseph I mentioned in the question that the transform variable is $t$.  Or it could be $x$, but then I would ask about a boundary condition in $u_x$.  I want the partial derivative in the boundary condition to match the transform variable.

Comment: Okay so if $t$ is the transform variable then the PDE would be $(ik)\hat{u}=\hat{u}_{xx}$ and the BC would be $(ik)\hat{u}(1,t)=\hat{t}$. Again, $\hat{t}$ would just be directly calculated from the definition of the Fourier Transform (i.e. actually calculating that integral).

Comment: Note that multiple transforms can be applied to a given problem to help simplify it in different ways. Usually, there is some defining property of the problem that would help inform you as to which to choose. For example, the Laplace transform can be used to analyze unstable systems whereas the Fourier transform generally cannot.